# Where does the @{ } come from in this foreach loop?

Tags: powershell, script, csv

I'm building a script to take a IP addresses from a CSV and then attempt to ping/connect to them.  Eventually I will run some commands against them and output all of it as extra data in the CSV.  Right now I'm working with 2 different CSVs (input and output) until I figure out the append process.

```
#Create a CSV
$CSVOutput = "$PSScriptRoot\Addresses scanned $(Get-Date -format “MM-dd-yyyy HHmm ss”).csv"
Write-Host "Creating output file " $CSVOutput
New-Item $CSVOutput -type file
$NewLine = "{0},{1}" -f "IPAddress", "Status"
$NewLine | add-content -path $CSVOutput

$inputCSV = "$PSScriptRoot\Addresses.csv"
$ipaddresses = import-csv $inputCSV | select-object "IPAddress" #$ColumnHeader

$inputCSV = "$PSScriptRoot\Addresses.csv"
$ipaddresses = import-csv $inputCSV
foreach($ip in $ipaddresses) {
Write-Host $ip
    if (test-connection $ip.("IPAddress") -count 1 -quiet) {
        $NewLine = "{0},{1}" -f $ip, "online"
        $NewLine | add-content -path $CSVOutput
    } else {
         write-host $ip.("IPAddress") "Ping failed." -foreground red
         $NewLine = "{0},{1}" -f $ip, "offline"
         $NewLine | add-content -path $CSVOutput
    }
}
```

For some strange reason, the script is outputting  the IP address in the form of `@{IPAddress=172.18.16.1}`, or if I comment out the piped output from the import line, I get this: `@{IPAddress=172.18.16.2; Status=}`.  In trying to debug this, I added `Write-Host $ip` as the first line in the `foreach` loop.

I can only guess I'm running into some kind of object vs string issue, or I am pulling in additional formatting somehow, but I can't get past it.  I only want to work with an actual IP address, I don't want the leading and trailing formatting `@{}`

What am I doing wrong?  How do I get rid of the extra formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change `$ip` in your `$NewLine` definition to `$ip.IPAddress`. `$ip` is of type PSCustomObject, where `$ip.IPAddress` is of type String.

You also haven't defined `$CSVOutput`, and should remove the second definition of `$ipaddresses`.

```
$inputCSV = ".\ipadr.csv"
$CSVOutput = ".\out.csv"
$ipaddresses = import-csv $inputCSV | select-object

foreach($ip in $ipaddresses) {
    Write-Host $ip.IPAddress
    if (test-connection $ip.IPAddress -count 1 -quiet) {
        $NewLine = "{0},{1}" -f $ip.IPAddress, "online"
        $NewLine | add-content -path $CSVOutput
    } else {
         write-host $ip.IPAddress "Ping failed." -foreground red
         $NewLine = "{0},{1}" -f $ip.IPAddress, "offline"
         $NewLine | add-content -path $CSVOutput
    }
}
```

Comment: `$ip.IPAddress` and `$ip.("IPAddress")` seem to give me the same result, which was what I was looking for.  Are they the same?

Comment: They are equivalent, though you only used either variant in the `if()` and not `$NewLine`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to get this working in a limited fashion, the main change is your ForEach loop, which I used this instead:  `$ipaddresses.IPAddress | ForEach-Object`.

The other change is in the Write-Host line to output Success/Failure:  `Write-Host $_ "Ping failed." -foreground red`.

Also, the $NewLine variable:  `$NewLine = "{0},{1}" -f $_, "online"`.

In the end, here's what I had that worked.  I wasn't able to fully test it as you will be able to, but using 2 IP's in my dummy Addresses.csv where one IP is legit the other isn't, it worked as I think you are expecting it to:

```
$inputCSV = "$PSScriptRoot\Addresses.csv"
$ipaddresses = Import-CSV $inputCSV
$ipaddresses.IPAddress | ForEach-Object {
    if (test-connection $_ -count 1 -quiet) {
        Write-Host $_ "Ping success." -foreground green
        $NewLine = "{0},{1}" -f $_, "online"
        $NewLine | add-content -path $CSVOutput
    } else {
         Write-Host $_ "Ping failed." -foreground red
         $NewLine = "{0},{1}" -f $_, "offline"
         $NewLine | add-content -path $CSVOutput
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the test connection must also use `$_` in your case

Comment: @eckes Good catch, editing Answer reflecting your comment.  :)

Comment: @root found my problem, but I'm still trying to digest your answer.  My next hurdle is to figure out how to get a faster fail, and I was thinking switching to a foreach-object might help speed things along.  But you guys lost me at `$_`.  Is that some kind of a reference to the pre-pipe object?  Maybe like a `this` reference or something?

Comment: @DanWhaley `$_` in a `For-Each` is the current object. For example, if you were parsing an array defined as `a, b, c` with `For-Each`, `$_` on the first run would equal a, on the second run equal b, and on the third run equal c.

Comment: *`ForEach-Object`

Answer (score 0):

A PowerShell way to create a new CSV file would be:

```
$OutputCSV = "$PSScriptRoot\AddressesChecked.csv"
$InputCSV = "$PSScriptRoot\Addresses.csv"

$IpAddresses = Import-Csv $InputCSV

$IPStatus = ForEach($IP in $IpAddresses.IPAddress) {
    If (Test-Connection $IP -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{IPAddress = $IP
                          Status    = "online"}
    } else {
        [PSCustomObject]@{IPAddress = $IP
                          Status    =  "offline"}
    }
}
$IPStatus | Export-Csv $OutputCSV -NoTypeInformation
$IPStatus
```

Sample Ouput to screen:

```
> .\SU_1235174.ps1

IPAddress     OnlineStatus
---------     ------------
192.168.1.1   online
192.168.1.60  offline
192.168.1.91  offline
192.168.1.92  offline
```

To Csv fle:

```
> gc .\AddressesChecked.csv
"IPAddress","OnlineStatus"
"192.168.1.1","online"
"192.168.1.60 ","offline"
"192.168.1.91 ","offline"
"192.168.1.92 ","offline"
```

Comment: I forgot to add the part of the script where I was creating the output file.  Added it to OP.